# Add notes to latex beamer and view them

Tags: beamer

Here https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/ac361549ac2186be0cdb

there is a MWE of creating a beamer presentation with added notes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

% These slides also contain speaker notes. You can print just the slides,
% just the notes, or both, depending on the setting below. Comment out the want
% you want.

%\setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
%\setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both

% To give a presentation with the Skim reader (http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) on OSX so
% that you see the notes on your laptop and the slides on the projector, do the following:
% 
% 1. Generate just the presentation (hide notes) and save to slides.pdf
% 2. Generate onlt the notes (show only nodes) and save to notes.pdf
% 3. With Skim open both slides.pdf and notes.pdf
% 4. Click on slides.pdf to bring it to front.
% 5. In Skim, under "View -> Presentation Option -> Synhcronized Noted Document"
%    select notes.pdf.
% 6. Now as you move around in slides.pdf the notes.pdf file will follow you.
% 7. Arrange windows so that notes.pdf is in full screen mode on your laptop
%    and slides.pdf is in presentation mode on the projector.

% Give a slight yellow tint to the notes page
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\pagecolor{yellow!5}\insertnote}\usepackage{palatino}

\title{How to make Beamer slides with notes}
\author{Andrej Bauer\\University of Ljubljana}
\date{\small Planet Earth}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage

  \note[item]{Thank the audience for being awake.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are
  \item some very boring bullets
  \item about nothing.
  \end{itemize}

  \note[item]{Note that this slide is boring.}

  \note[item]{Observe that there are no actual bullets here.}

  \note[item]{Future work: add another bullet.}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The author says (comments of the code)

```
%To give a presentation with the Skim reader (http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) %on OSX so
% that you see the notes on your laptop and the slides on the projector, do %the following:
% 
% 1. Generate just the presentation (hide notes) and save to slides.pdf
% 2. Generate onlt the notes (show only nodes) and save to notes.pdf
% 3. With Skim open both slides.pdf and notes.pdf
% 4. Click on slides.pdf to bring it to front.
% 5. In Skim, under "View -> Presentation Option -> Synhcronized Noted Document"
%    select notes.pdf.
% 6. Now as you move around in slides.pdf the notes.pdf file will follow you.
% 7. Arrange windows so that notes.pdf is in full screen mode on your laptop
%    and slides.pdf is in presentation mode on the projector.
```

What are the alternatives (Ubuntu and Windows) to Skim which is only for Mac?
In general, how can one proceed using only a traditional pdf viewer (e.g. Adobe for windows, Okular for Ubuntu)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have never tried it but maybe Pympress could work (https://www.scivision.dev/beamer-latex-dual-display-pdf-notes/), or https://dspdfviewer.danny-edel.de/.

Comment: Or https://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/dohmen/dohmen.pdf.

Comment: @Dimitris, what did you end up using? Having the same issue now - what's doid you find to be the best course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pympress](https://github.com/Cimbali/pympress/) works wonderfully - a software available across platforms, to view in two separate windows the slides and the notes.
see
https://web.archive.org/web/20200926120718/https://www.scivision.dev/beamer-latex-dual-display-pdf-notes/

In general, please examine chapter 19 of the [beamer user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on notes.